# Powershell adding unwanted decimals (addition)

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am doing some addition in one of my scripts, here is some simplified code:

```
foreach($entry in $arr){
...
switch($entry.AccessRights)
{

"GenericRead" {$score = 1}
"GenericWrite" {$score = 2}
"GenericAll" {$score = 3}
default {$score = 0.1}
}
$users | where {$_.username -eq $entry.username} | % {$_.aclscore+=$score}
}
```

You would expect the output to be something like 123.5 or something. But at some point in between (when the score is 0.1) it deviates by 0.0000000000001 plus or minus, so i might get results like 66,1000000000001 or even 84,8999999999999.

Question 1: Why?

Question 2: What can i do to work around that apart from rounding afterwards?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On testing, PowerShell is implicitly casting to the datatype of your variable to `[double]`. Instead, explicitly cast as `[decimal]`

- Double datatype can hold a wide range of values, but sacrifices exact precision.
- Decimal uses more memory (12 bytes as oppose to 8 in double) and has a shorter range of values but retains precision.

This is by no means an in-depth comparison; I recommend you read [this table of datatypes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs7y5x0x(v=vs.90).aspx) and look online for a more complete explanation as this is very fundamental and is language-agnostic.

**Code**

```
foreach($entry in $arr){
    ...
    switch($entry.AccessRights)
    {

        "GenericRead" {[decimal]$score = 1}
        "GenericWrite" {[decimal]$score = 2}
        "GenericAll" {[decimal]$score = 3}
        default {[decimal]$score = 0.1}

    }

    $users | where {$_.username -eq $entry.username} | % {$_.aclscore+=$score}

}
```

---

**Edit - Further explanation**

Lack of precision in the double data type arises because numbers are stored in [binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number), and some numbers cannot be expressed exactly in binary.

Walter Mitty's comment provides a good example of a `1/3`, a number that cannot be expressed exactly using a finite number of digits in decimal, or in binary:

```
1/3 = 0.333333333..... [decimal]
1/3 = 0.010101010..... [binary]
```

Similarly, the fraction `1/10` [cannot be expressed exactly in binary](http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/). Whereas it can in decimal.

```
1/10 = 0.1             [decimal]
1/10 = 0.000110011.... [binary]
```

Comment: Retains precision for decmal fractins, yes.  For anumber like one third, both double and decimal will represent it as an approximation.

Comment: @WalterMitty True. OP is using `0.1` do I didn't get into the general cases. Added explanation on the decimal/binary fractions